# Is there a User Agent list for .Net and the other aspects of the HTTP_USER_AGENT output?

Tags: php, user-agent

I am creating a script that will show your computer information in Non-Geekeese. This is a dirty script so I know I have not cleaned it up yet, so please refrain from saying so.

I am looking for a site that breaks down the HTTP_USER_AGENT output into something more understandable to the end user.

For now it only shows OS and Browser, I want to incorporate several other aspects such as for windows systems show .Net versions, what type of processor using other outputs if I need to, etc...

Is there a place on the web that shows the data broken down, even if it is on a list. I have one for browsers, and OS's as shown, but it seems that is all everyone else wants.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

```
<?php
//This is a script that will identify the OS and browser you are using. This also has a fix in where Chrome shows up as Chrome, and not show up as Safari by accident. 



//Booleans to set OS and Browser to False.
$os = false;
$browser = false;
//Booleans for Web Browser & OS Functions.
$info = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$xp = 'Windows NT 5.1';
$vista = 'Windows NT 6.0';
$win7 = 'Windows NT 6.1';
$ubuntu = 'Ubuntu';
$ie106 = 'MSIE 10.6;';
$ie10 = 'MSIE 10.0;';
$ie9 = 'MSIE 9.0;';
$ie8 = 'MSIE 8.0;';
$ie7b = 'MSIE 7.0b;';
$ie7 = 'MSIE 7.0;';
$chrome = '/Chrome/';
$safari = '/Safari/';
$firefox = '/Firefox/';

print $info;

print '<br /><br />';
//Operating Systems
if (stristr($info, "Windows NT 5.1")) {echo 'You are using a Windows XP Operating System ';}
if (stristr($info, "Windows NT 6.0")) {echo 'You are using a Windows Vista Operating System ';}
if (stristr($info, "Windows NT 6.1")) {echo 'You are using a Windows 7 Operating System ';}
if (stristr($info, "Ubuntu")) {echo 'You are using an Ubuntu Operating System ';}
if (stristr($info, "Mac OS")) {echo 'You are using a Macintosh Operating System ';}


//Web Browsers
if (stristr($info, "Chrome") !== FALSE) {stristr($info,"Safari");
        $chrome = 'Chrome';
            echo 'with a Chrome Web Browser ';}
elseif (stristr($info, "Safari")) {echo 'with a Safari Web Browser ';}
if (stristr($info, "Firefox")) {echo 'with a Firefox Web Browser ';}
if (stristr($info, "MSIE 7.0;")) {echo 'with a Internet Explorer 7.0 Web Browser ';}
if (stristr($info, "MSIE 7.0b;")) {echo 'with a Internet Explorer 7.0b Web Browser ';}
if (stristr($info, "MSIE 8.0;")) {echo 'with a Internet Explorer 8.0 Web Browser ';}
if (stristr($info, "MSIE 9.0;")) {echo 'with a Internet Explorer 9.0 Web Browser ';}
if (stristr($info, "MSIE 10.0;")) {echo 'with a Internet Explorer 10.0 Web Browser ';}
if (stristr($info, "MSIE 10.6;")) {echo 'with a Internet Explorer 10.6 Web Browser ';}



//If OS or Browser not found in list.
if ($ubuntu || $xp || $vista || $win7)
$os = true;

if($firefox || $chrome || $safari || $ie9 || $ie8)
$browser = true;

if(!$browser || !$os){

echo'<strong>';
echo '<br />' . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . '<br /><br />Administrator someone in your work force is using an unsupported browser or OS, please email this information to the developer of the software you are using. It will allow your browser/OS combination  to be used correctly. Sorry for the inconvenience.</strong> <br /><br />Please copy and paste the text above and send it to your web administrator. It will explain everything he/she needs to do.<br />';}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's CodeIgniter user agents list:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| USER AGENT TYPES
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| This file contains four arrays of user agent data.  It is used by the
| User Agent Class to help identify browser, platform, robot, and
| mobile device data.  The array keys are used to identify the device
| and the array values are used to set the actual name of the item.
|
*/

$platforms = array (
                    'windows nt 6.0'    => 'Windows Longhorn',
                    'windows nt 5.2'    => 'Windows 2003',
                    'windows nt 5.0'    => 'Windows 2000',
                    'windows nt 5.1'    => 'Windows XP',
                    'windows nt 4.0'    => 'Windows NT 4.0',
                    'winnt4.0'          => 'Windows NT 4.0',
                    'winnt 4.0'         => 'Windows NT',
                    'winnt'             => 'Windows NT',
                    'windows 98'        => 'Windows 98',
                    'win98'             => 'Windows 98',
                    'windows 95'        => 'Windows 95',
                    'win95'             => 'Windows 95',
                    'windows'           => 'Unknown Windows OS',
                    'os x'              => 'Mac OS X',
                    'ppc mac'           => 'Power PC Mac',
                    'freebsd'           => 'FreeBSD',
                    'ppc'               => 'Macintosh',
                    'linux'             => 'Linux',
                    'debian'            => 'Debian',
                    'sunos'             => 'Sun Solaris',
                    'beos'              => 'BeOS',
                    'apachebench'       => 'ApacheBench',
                    'aix'               => 'AIX',
                    'irix'              => 'Irix',
                    'osf'               => 'DEC OSF',
                    'hp-ux'             => 'HP-UX',
                    'netbsd'            => 'NetBSD',
                    'bsdi'              => 'BSDi',
                    'openbsd'           => 'OpenBSD',
                    'gnu'               => 'GNU/Linux',
                    'unix'              => 'Unknown Unix OS'
                );


// The order of this array should NOT be changed. Many browsers return
// multiple browser types so we want to identify the sub-type first.
$browsers = array(
                    'Flock'             => 'Flock',
                    'Chrome'            => 'Chrome',
                    'Opera'             => 'Opera',
                    'MSIE'              => 'Internet Explorer',
                    'Internet Explorer' => 'Internet Explorer',
                    'Shiira'            => 'Shiira',
                    'Firefox'           => 'Firefox',
                    'Chimera'           => 'Chimera',
                    'Phoenix'           => 'Phoenix',
                    'Firebird'          => 'Firebird',
                    'Camino'            => 'Camino',
                    'Netscape'          => 'Netscape',
                    'OmniWeb'           => 'OmniWeb',
                    'Safari'            => 'Safari',
                    'Mozilla'           => 'Mozilla',
                    'Konqueror'         => 'Konqueror',
                    'icab'              => 'iCab',
                    'Lynx'              => 'Lynx',
                    'Links'             => 'Links',
                    'hotjava'           => 'HotJava',
                    'amaya'             => 'Amaya',
                    'IBrowse'           => 'IBrowse'
                );

$mobiles = array(
                    // legacy array, old values commented out
                    'mobileexplorer'    => 'Mobile Explorer',
//                  'openwave'          => 'Open Wave',
//                  'opera mini'        => 'Opera Mini',
//                  'operamini'         => 'Opera Mini',
//                  'elaine'            => 'Palm',
                    'palmsource'        => 'Palm',
//                  'digital paths'     => 'Palm',
//                  'avantgo'           => 'Avantgo',
//                  'xiino'             => 'Xiino',
                    'palmscape'         => 'Palmscape',
//                  'nokia'             => 'Nokia',
//                  'ericsson'          => 'Ericsson',
//                  'blackberry'        => 'BlackBerry',
//                  'motorola'          => 'Motorola'

                    // Phones and Manufacturers
                    'motorola'          => "Motorola",
                    'nokia'             => "Nokia",
                    'palm'              => "Palm",
                    'iphone'            => "Apple iPhone",
                    'ipad'              => "iPad",
                    'ipod'              => "Apple iPod Touch",
                    'sony'              => "Sony Ericsson",
                    'ericsson'          => "Sony Ericsson",
                    'blackberry'        => "BlackBerry",
                    'cocoon'            => "O2 Cocoon",
                    'blazer'            => "Treo",
                    'lg'                => "LG",
                    'amoi'              => "Amoi",
                    'xda'               => "XDA",
                    'mda'               => "MDA",
                    'vario'             => "Vario",
                    'htc'               => "HTC",
                    'samsung'           => "Samsung",
                    'sharp'             => "Sharp",
                    'sie-'              => "Siemens",
                    'alcatel'           => "Alcatel",
                    'benq'              => "BenQ",
                    'ipaq'              => "HP iPaq",
                    'mot-'              => "Motorola",
                    'playstation portable'  => "PlayStation Portable",
                    'hiptop'            => "Danger Hiptop",
                    'nec-'              => "NEC",
                    'panasonic'         => "Panasonic",
                    'philips'           => "Philips",
                    'sagem'             => "Sagem",
                    'sanyo'             => "Sanyo",
                    'spv'               => "SPV",
                    'zte'               => "ZTE",
                    'sendo'             => "Sendo",

                    // Operating Systems
                    'symbian'               => "Symbian",
                    'SymbianOS'             => "SymbianOS",
                    'elaine'                => "Palm",
                    'palm'                  => "Palm",
                    'series60'              => "Symbian S60",
                    'windows ce'            => "Windows CE",

                    // Browsers
                    'obigo'                 => "Obigo",
                    'netfront'              => "Netfront Browser",
                    'openwave'              => "Openwave Browser",
                    'mobilexplorer'         => "Mobile Explorer",
                    'operamini'             => "Opera Mini",
                    'opera mini'            => "Opera Mini",

                    // Other
                    'digital paths'         => "Digital Paths",
                    'avantgo'               => "AvantGo",
                    'xiino'                 => "Xiino",
                    'novarra'               => "Novarra Transcoder",
                    'vodafone'              => "Vodafone",
                    'docomo'                => "NTT DoCoMo",
                    'o2'                    => "O2",

                    // Fallback
                    'mobile'                => "Generic Mobile",
                    'wireless'              => "Generic Mobile",
                    'j2me'                  => "Generic Mobile",
                    'midp'                  => "Generic Mobile",
                    'cldc'                  => "Generic Mobile",
                    'up.link'               => "Generic Mobile",
                    'up.browser'            => "Generic Mobile",
                    'smartphone'            => "Generic Mobile",
                    'cellphone'             => "Generic Mobile"
                );

// There are hundreds of bots but these are the most common.
$robots = array(
                    'googlebot'         => 'Googlebot',
                    'msnbot'            => 'MSNBot',
                    'slurp'             => 'Inktomi Slurp',
                    'yahoo'             => 'Yahoo',
                    'askjeeves'         => 'AskJeeves',
                    'fastcrawler'       => 'FastCrawler',
                    'infoseek'          => 'InfoSeek Robot 1.0',
                    'lycos'             => 'Lycos'
                );

/* End of file user_agents.php */
/* Location: ./application/config/user_agents.php */
```

Comment: But would this work? I'm looking at the list and it would confuse Safari and Chrome... or am I mistaken?

Comment: CI is a modern and clean framework. The programmers of CI would never put something that make problem in their structure. You can even see the difference between `icab` and `iCab` is just a low case word and it can be an evidence that they clearly did a great job for putting foucs. If you're not convinced you can check each of them on the internet. The reason that you can't see some of the agents is because they are no longer supported. This will help developers to not worry about different old versions of heck browsers!

Comment: Chrome shows up as Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.63 Safari/535.7 using the $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] command. This means if you do what you suggest it will show up as Chrome Safari... I can fix it so it doesn't show up, but the way you have it may not work... I've yet to test out your script entirely.

Comment: @Matt - I didn't test it because CI would operate these lists itself. I've got a complete list for mobile devices but it's not gonna fit your work cuz you want browsers. The thing that I know about user agents names is their engine. Maybe Chrome and Firefox are using the same engine, In that case I have no idea to how to find the right name.